# Finding unit vector from directional derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I was given this question where $f(x, y) = x^2 + xy^2$ and I have to find the unit vector at the point $(2, 1)$ when the directional derivative has the value of $2.$ I am still quite confused on how to do this as I am still a beginner :( pls help

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I'm not sure.. you are given the unit vector already..? or maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

The gradient of $f$ in $p(2,1)$ is $\begin{pmatrix}5\\4\end{pmatrix}$. As the directional derivative of $f$ in $p$ in direction of the unit vector $\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\end{pmatrix}$, that is, $u^2+v^2=1$, is the product of the gradient and the direction vector, we derive that  $5u+4v=2$. Now solve for $u$ and $v$.

Comment: i see. but why is u^2+v^2=1.? that part i did not learn about

Comment: You want $(u,v)$ to be a unit vector, don't you?